# How to apply a function to the values of one column, then take the output and apply it to multiple other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, lambda

Alright y'all, maybe my strategy here isn't ideal, but I've got a very awkward dataset to work with and I need help.

I have a pandas dataframe that's structured such that only the first column has values:

```
df = 
|Ind| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| - | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 0 | String1  | Null     | Null     |
| 1 | String2  | Null     | Null     |
```

What I'd like to do is iteratively take the value from Column A and put it through a function whose output is a list. From there I need to fill the remaining columns with the output of the function, such that:

```
df = 
|Ind| Column A | Column B         | Column C         |
| - | -------- | ---------------- | ---------------- |
| 0 | String1  | func(String1)[0] | func(String1)[1] |
| 1 | String2  | func(String2)[0] | func(String2)[1] |
```

Thus far I've been trying to do this using anonymous functions, as such:

```
df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda y: df["Column A"].apply(lambda x: list(map(func, x)))
```

Which almost does what I want, but does not map the list into the respective columns, and the result is instead:

```
df = 
|Ind| Column A | Column B      | Column C      |
| - | -------- | ------------- | ------------- |
| 0 | String1  | func(String1) | func(String1) |
| 1 | String2  | func(String2) | func(String2) |
```

If there's a better approach I'm totally open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functional programming is not as fun as they say it is. Here's a procedural version, that applies a function to each value in the column, and extends the data frame. Note that the function can return a variable number of results.

```
import pandas as pd
# Make a three row, one column data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(["foo","bar","fubar"],columns=["Column A"])
# Apply to column 1 and create new rows (variable length is fine)
def fun(s):
    return list(c for c in s)
# Make a new data frame by applying function
df2 = pd.DataFrame(fun(s) for s in df["Column A"])
# Name new columns (first column remains same)
column_names = {i:f"Column {'ABCDEFGHIJK'[i+1]}" for i in range(len(df2.columns))}
# And add new columns using new names
df = pd.concat([df,df2 ],axis=1).rename(columns=column_names)
df
```

[image: Resulting data frame:]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary helper column with the list and then drop it at the end, like this:

```
df['temporary'] = df['Column A'].map(func)
df['Column B'] = df['temporary'].str[0]
df['Column C'] = df['temporary'].str[1]
df = df.drop('temporary', axis=1)
```